# How to set the value of the dropdown in knockout js?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have two dropdowns in my page.
One loads on ready and the other one loads after the first dropdown is selected.

```
var ViewModel = function() {
   var self = this;
   self.DropDownA = ko.observableArray();
   self.DropDownB = ko.observableArray();
   self.selectedDDA = ko.observable();
   self.selectedDDB = ko.observable();

   $.getJSON("api/GetA",function(result) {
      ko.mapping.fromJS(result,{},self);
   });
   self.selectedDDA.subscribe(function(value) {
      $.getJSON("api/GetB/value",function(result) {
          ko.mapping.fromJS(result,{},self);
   });
   });
}
```

Now my question is this, if the values of A and B are set in hidden values, how do I preload the selected values?  I tried this but it does not work:

```
self.selectedDDA( $("#hiddenValue").val());
```

Please help. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering... where are you setting that value. I would probably make sure it is set after the data has been populated

```
 $.getJSON("api/GetA",function(result) {
     ko.mapping.fromJS(result,{},self);
     self.selectedDDA( $("#hiddenValue").val());
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

By your description

> "One loads on ready and the other one loads after the first dropdown
>   is selected. "

and your use of:

```
self.selectedDDA( $("#hiddenValue").val());
```

This sounds like you might need to rethink how you are coding this.  Note that in knockout or some other JS frameworks, you really should not be doing direct DOM reads/writes/changes.  You should represent your model in Knockout JS code only.  Knockout will handle the DOM updates for you.  If you provide more code I can show more details.